# Efficient way to compare two sets of different type

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, guava

First of all I need some very efficient solution as I am comparing collections with >300k elements.

At the beginning we have two different classes

```
Class A {
   String keyA;
   String keyB;
   String keyC;
}

Class B {
   String keyA;
   String keyB;
   String keyC;
   String name;
   String code;

   toA() {
     return new A(keyA, keyB, keyC);
   }
}
```

Both of them contains several fields which are composed key(in this example key of three columns = keyA keyB keyC)

This composed key makes calculation very long for primitive brute forces using nested loops.
So I figured out that the most efficient way would be to transform second class to first one using method toA
and then I can safely compare them using for example google's api using Sets efficiency

```
Set<A> collectionA = <300k of elements>
Set<B> collectionB = <300k of elements>
Set<A> collectionBConvertedToA = collectionB.stream().map(item -> item.toA()).collect(toSet())

Set<A> result = Sets.differences(collectionBConvertedToA, collectionA); // very fast first full scan comparison

Set<String> changedNames = result.stream()
     .map(outer -> collectionB.stream()
                               // very slow second full scan comparison
                              .filter(inner -> inner.getKeyA().equals(outer.getKeyA()) 
                                           && inner.getKeyB().equals(outer.getKeyB()) 
                                           && inner.getKeyC().equals(outer.getKeyC()))
                              .findFirst()
                              .map(item -> item.getName()))
     .collect(toSet());
log.info("changed names" + changedNames);
```

Guava Sets.differences can find differences on Sets >300k in less than 1/10 of second but later on I still have full scan anyway to collect names.

I am just guessing, but is there something like

```
Set<B> result = Sets.differences(setA, setB, a -> a.customHashCode(), b -> b.customHashCode(), (a, b) -> a.customEquals(b))
```

with custom hashCode and custom equals methods to keep Sets efficiency or there is some better pattern to make such comparison as I believe it seems like common problem ?

EDIT
I just figured out that I can just flip conversion to extended class

```
toB() {
  return new B(keyA, keyB, keyC, null, null);
}
```

but then I need override hashCode and equals to use only those 3 fields and I still believe there is more elegant way

Comment: Your `B.toA()` does not *cast* a `B` instance.  Rather, it creates a whole brand new `A` with property values taken from the `B`.  That is much more costly  than casting would be, if casting between these types were possible (it isn't).  That may nevertheless be a reasonable way forward, but be sure you understand what's actually happening here.

Comment: indeed but I just used wrong word. I edited post, thanks.

Comment: I have edited the type of `collectionBConvertedToA` as `Set<A>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `O(n^2)` since you are streaming `collectionB` for each element in result. The following should work pretty fast:

```
Set<String> changedNames = collectionB.stream()
                              .filter(b -> collectionA.contains(b.toA())
                              .map(item -> item.getName()).collect(toSet());
```

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple -.- I will wait a litte bit for more responses, but I dont think there is smth more elegant, thanks

Answer (score 0):

We could stream the first set and for each `A` object, concatenate the three fields of `A` by a delimiter and collect it as a Set (`Set<String>`).

Then we go over the elements of the second set, compose a string based on the key fields of A and check if the above-computed set has it or not.

```
Set<String> keysOfA = collectionA.stream()
        .map(a -> compose(a.getKeyA(), a.getKeyB(), a.getKeyC()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Set<String> changedNames = collectionB.stream()
        .filter(b -> !keysOfA.contains(compose(b.getKeyA(), b.getKeyB(), b.getKeyC())))
        .map(b -> b.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

static String compose(String keyA, String keyB, String keyC) {
    return keyA + "|" + keyB + "|" + keyC; //any other delimiter would work
}
```

With this you don't need the `toA()` method.

---

**Second approach:**

If class `A` implements equals and hashcode, then you can do like

```
Set<String> changedNames = collectionB.stream()
        .filter(b -> !collectionA.contains(b.toA()))
        .map(b -> b.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```